# How can a QThread send a signal from its own thread with an enum as an argument for consumption in QML?

Tags: qt, enums, qml, signals-slots, qthread

In the following code, if the signal `errorHappened` is emitted from the main thread it works without problem. However if it is emitted from the `QThread` thread it fails with the following error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ErrorCode'
(Make sure 'ErrorCode' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Is there a way that the signal can be successfully emitted from the `QThread` thread? If so, how?

[Full code in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/paulmasri/a1e225516368e50ee4ac3f748779e758)

**MyClass.h**

```
#import <QThread>
#import <atomic>

class MyClass : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MyClass(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~MyClass() override;

    enum ErrorCode {
        ErrorA,
        ErrorB,
        ErrorC
    };
    Q_ENUM(ErrorCode)

signals:
    void errorHappened(ErrorCode errorCode);

public slots:
    void mainThreadError();
    void otherThreadError();

private:
    std::atomic<bool> m_running;
    std::atomic<bool> m_signalStop;
    std::atomic<bool> m_signalError;

    void run() override;
    void stop();
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyClass.h"

MyClass::MyClass(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    start();
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    stop();
}

void MyClass::mainThreadError()
{
    emit errorHappened(ErrorCode::ErrorA);
}

void MyClass::otherThreadError()
{
    m_signalError = true;
}

void MyClass::run()
{
    m_running = true;

    while (!m_signalStop) {
        if (m_signalError) {
            emit errorHappened(ErrorCode::ErrorA);
            m_signalError = false;
        }
        msleep(1);
    }

    m_running = false;
    m_signalStop = false;
}

void MyClass::stop()
{
    if (m_running) {
        m_signalStop = true;
        wait();
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include "MyClass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();

    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass");

    view->setSource((QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"))));
    view->create();
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import MyClass 1.0

Rectangle {
    id: root

    width: 800
    height: 600
    focus: true

    MyClass {
        id: tester
        onErrorHappened: {
            var s
            switch (errorCode) {
            case MyClass.ErrorA:
                s = "Error A happened"
                break
            }
            console.log(s)
        }
    }

    Row {
        spacing: 30

        Button {
            id: mainThreadButton

            enabled: !tester.testRunning
            text: "Test on main thread"
            onClicked: tester.mainThreadError()
        }

        Button {
            id: otherThreadButton

            enabled: !tester.testRunning
            text: "Test on other thread"
            onClicked: tester.otherThreadError()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that qRegisterMetaType() != qmlRegisterType()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qmlRegisterType makes the QObject (MyClass) class accessible in QML (Q_PROPERTY, Q_ENUM, Q_SIGNAL, Q_SLOT, Q_INVOKABLE, etc.) but does not allow the transmission of data between threads, for this case it must be registered using `qRegisterMetaType<MyClass::ErrorCode>("ErrorCode")`:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include "MyClass.h"

static void registerTypes(){
    qRegisterMetaType<MyClass::ErrorCode>("ErrorCode");
    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyClass", 1, 0, "MyClass");
}

Q_COREAPP_STARTUP_FUNCTION(registerTypes)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource((QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"))));
    view.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your opening paragraph - is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @PaulMasri-Stone It is not explicit but can be deduced from the docs and the error.

Answer (score 0):

your type "ErrorCode" defined only in thread (not in main)

1. For user defined types you can use (read this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html)

   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ErrorCode);
2. Use standard types for arguments (int,QMap,QString....)

Comment: Where did you get that information? I never read that in any of the docs.

Comment: I don't believe this is relevant. The macro `Q_ENUM` was created to handle declaring/registering metatype within itself. Note that if I cause `MyClass::mainThreadError()` to be called, it works perfectly. The problem is only when the signal is triggered from the `QThread` thread, e.g. by causing `MyClass::otherThreadError()` to be called.